# Switching from blogspot to custom domain

Tags: url, dns, seo, blogs

I have a blog on blogspot with url say `myblog.blogspot.com`. Now its getting around `30,000` page view in a month. I want to change the blog url as `myblog.com`.

But, I worry that the amount of traffic I have gained till now, will become nil because of new url. Google page rank and alexa rank will go to nil.

So, should I change the domain of my blog or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you migrate from a sub-domain of blogspot to your own domain you **must** set up proper redirects.   The redirects should be the permanent (301) type, not the temporary (302) variety).  Permalinks should redirect directly to corresponding permalinks:

- `http://myblog.blogspot.com/` -> `http://myblog.com/`
- `http://myblog.blogspot.com/this-is-a-blog-post` -> `http://myblog.com/this-is-a-blog-post`

You should also make sure you change all your internal links to make sure they don't mention your old sub-domain.  If you control any external links, you should change those.  You might even consider asking some webmasters to change the external links that point to your blog.

Even if you do the redirects correctly, there is a good chance that you will lose Google traffic for some time.  The last time I tried a move from a sub-domain to a full domain (several years ago), I lost about 75% of my Google referrals for about 8 months.  After 8 months, Google seemed to trust my new domain again and my traffic came right back.

[Google has a change of address tool as part of webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/change-address).  It is limited to use on "full-domains" and it won't work in your case because you are starting out on a sub-domain.  Google has a [help document that goes along with it](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105) which you may still find useful.

Comment: From your response and from my findings on google, I conclude that I can change the domain, redirect it but I will lose my search engine traffic, pagerank, alexa rank, although not permanently but yes for sometime.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this Link will help you: [How do I use a custom domain](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&hlrm=de&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs)
It s a simple forward, so your rankings will not go to nil.

> Your original Blogspot address will automatically forward to your new domain. That way, any existing links or bookmarks to your site will still work.